# NLTK ValueError: Unable to parse line 1: S -> NP-SBJ VP . Expected a nonterminal, found:

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am new to NLP and now I want to parse a lot of sentences(about 10000) to get their CFG trees. Before that I have to build a grammar to parse them. I try to use NLTK treebank, but they can not be load as grammar. I do not know why, could anyone please give me some advice?

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import treebank
nltk.download('treebank')

treeData = treebank.parsed_sents()
treeData_rules = []
for sent in treeData:
    for production in sent.productions():
        treeData_rules.append(production)

test = open("test.cfg","w+")
for i in range(len(treeData_rules)):
    test.write(str(treeData_rules[i]))
    test.write('\n')
test.close()

grammar1 = nltk.data.load('file:test.cfg')
```

And it give me an error:
**
ValueError: Unable to parse line 1: S -> NP-SBJ VP .
Expected a nonterminal, found: .
**

I do not know why NLTK can not load NLTK treebank grammars..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but the normal form of phrase structure grammars does not allow terminal symbols as a category on the derivation side. That is why it says "expected a nonterminal". The only terminal symbol to be found in your rule (S-> NP-SUBJ VP .) is the dot ".", in case this is not a copy paste error that the "." belongs to the rule. Remove the dot and try again, then it should work.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I also considered like this, Once I removed the ".", it would work well. However, the treebank has a million of dataset, it is impossible to delete every mistake one by one. Now I try to use spaCy to parse the sentence and it is successful. I just wondered why NLTK treebank can not be loaded by NLTK loader